# Frame from video is upside down after extracting

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

My problem here is that when I extracting a video into a frame using opencv, sometimes the frame that I get will flip up which happened to me for both my machine(window) and VM(ubuntu) But some of the video I tested, frames are not flip. So, I wonder what factor or what should be changed/added in my code to make the extract fixed without a flip

```
def extract_frame(video,folder):
   global fps

   os.mkdir('./green_frame/{folder}/'.format(folder=folder))
   vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
   success,image = vidcap.read()
   fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
   count = 0
   success = True
   while success:  #os.path.join(pathOut,(name+'.png'))
      cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('./green_frame/{folder}/'.format(folder=folder),"frame%d.png" % count), image)
      success,image = vidcap.read()
      print('Read a new frame: ', success) 
      count += 1
```

This is the example of frame I get from this code.
[image: flip]
Which my orginal video that I used is upside down like this:[image]

So, in my case, what I have to changed to make it not flip like my first picture. Is it relate to the resolution or framerate of the video? I tested with a 1280x720 resolution video and all of the frame extracted are flipped upside down but a frame from video with a 568x320 is normal

Thank you

Edit:
So, I look at the information of the video and I found out that in the metadata, it has rotate 180 for the video that extract to an upside down frame
[image]
But when I check with a normal video that produced a non upside-down frame, it does not have rotate:180
[image]

So from this, how can I deal with a video that has a rotation?

Comment: Videos have a property called ‘orientation’. I bet in your case it would be set to 180.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the 'orientation' property location?. I cannot find it in the properties option. @DmitriiZ.

Comment: You can get it with ffmpeg CLI

Comment: Oh I use `ffmpeg -i videoname.mp4` and it show that it rotate 180 the same as you said. But how can I fix this from my source code?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this with opencv (as far as I know you can't), you can try 3rd party libraries like ffmpeg or [hackoir](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir-metadata/)

Comment: So ideally to prevent this, I have to write a function that check wheter the input video's metadata has a rotation = 180 or not. If yes, do something that make it be as normal else continue script(there are other script that need to be process base on the video), kind of that, right?

Comment: Exactly. Note that it can also be 90 and 270.

Comment: My solution that surprisingly work for me is that I changed the code that I wrote to write a video from `ffmpeg_extract_subclip(video, t1, t2, targetname=output)` to use write_videofile() function instead and it not produce a rotation 180 in the property. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 28):

**Update Sep 28, 2022**

This problem can now be solved by simply updating to OpenCV v4.5 and above.

If upgrading is a problem follow the old answer, below.

---

For anyone still looking into this, I was just stuck on the same problem. Turns out some Android phones and iPhones take images/frames in landscape and convert them on the fly according to the exif 'rotate' tag to display the images/frames.

Weird design choice in OpenCV is that `cv2.imread(img_file)` already reads the image in correct orientation by reading the image's `rotate` tag, but the `cv2.VideoStream`'s `read()` method does not do this.

So, to fix this I used `ffmpeg` to read the 'rotate' tag and rotate the video frame to its correct orientation.(Big thanks to the comments above, for pointing me in the right direction )

Following is the code:

- Make sure you have `ffmpeg` for python. (`pip install ffmpeg-python`)
- Create a method to check  if rotation is required by the video_file:

  ```
   import ffmpeg    

   def check_rotation(path_video_file):
       # this returns meta-data of the video file in form of a dictionary
       meta_dict = ffmpeg.probe(path_video_file)

       # from the dictionary, meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate'] is the key
       # we are looking for
       rotateCode = None
       if int(meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate']) == 90:
           rotateCode = cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE
       elif int(meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate']) == 180:
           rotateCode = cv2.ROTATE_180
       elif int(meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate']) == 270:
           rotateCode = cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE

       return rotateCode
  ```
- Create a method to correct the rotation of the frame in video file:

  ```
   def correct_rotation(frame, rotateCode):  
       return cv2.rotate(frame, rotateCode)
  ```
- Finally, do this in your main loop:

  ```
   # open a pointer to the video file stream
   vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

   # check if video requires rotation
   rotateCode = check_rotation(video_path)

   # loop over frames from the video file stream
   while True:
       # grab the frame from the file
       grabbed, frame = vs.read()

       # if frame not grabbed -> end of the video
       if not grabbed:
           break

       # check if the frame needs to be rotated
       if rotateCode is not None:
           frame = correct_rotation(frame, rotateCode)

       # now your logic can start from here
  ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you have this working on Python 3.7?  I'm running into some issues with ffmpeg, and it seems like maybe it's because it's meant for Python 2

Comment: @stranger really? I came up with this when I was using Python 3.6. I'll report back in a little while

Comment: @stranger working fine on python 3.6. The `ffmpeg-python` lib was updated to version 0.2.0 a few months back with Python 3.7 support. Maybe update your package. Check out the project here:

https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: thanks for your response, I was able to get it working for mp4 videos :)  I don't suppose you have a trick for .MOV files as well, do you?

Comment: I figured it out, the `rotation` information was on a different stream

Comment: @stranger Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, I haven't worked with .MOV files

Comment: no problem, thanks for following up.  I ended up figuring it out :)  Left an additional comment for posterity.

Comment: @RafayKhan I used your code but in the "meta_dict" there is no rotate flag.I am using 5.0.1 version on a mac.

Comment: @LuckySunda In that case, it might be possible that there is no metadata in the video file. You can check EXIF data online for your file using something like https://exifmeta.com/

Comment: Not every video has `'rotate'` tag and not every video has `'tags'`. It would be good to fix answer code with some `if`s catching this situations. @RafayKhan

Comment: I have a video sample that should be rotated 180 degrees but rotation info in metadata is 90 degrees so it is wrong. I have another video that has no need for rotation but metadata rotation info is also 90 degrees.

Comment: Using version 4.6 and I still get this error and this solution did not fix it. I get "KeyError: 'rotate'"

Comment: Edit: I had to install v4.5 because 4.6 is broken. Kinda ridiculous but it works.

Comment: @Frobot, check one of the comments above, rotation parameters could be in a different key depending on the video container.

Comment: @s.paszko any idea what could be the possible keys where rotate tag could be? Is there some wiki for this kinda stuff?

Comment: @mcsahin same here, I have a video that is supposed to rotate 180 but the metadata is 90. I used iPhone to capture the video. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the following will solve the problem of opening some videos upside-down.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_MSMF)
```

Answer (score 3):

When I recently ran into this issue, I found that all that was required was to update to OpenCV v4.5:

- This is the related Github issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15499
- Here is the commit: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/f0271e54d90b3af62301f531f5f00995b00d7cd6

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31674699)

Comment: The essential part of my answer is: "update to OpenCV v4.5". Thanks! :)

Comment: NOTE: This feature is broken in opencv 4.6 downgrade to version 4.5.5.64 for frames to be auto saved according to input videos rotation. For reference: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22088. To downgrade use, pip uninstall opencv-python, pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer given the package has taken the direction that this should be implemented by default since v4.5

Answer (score 1):

The rotate tag is optional so the check_rotation will fail,
This code fix it:

```
def check_rotation(path_video_file):
    # this returns meta-data of the video file in form of a dictionary
    meta_dict = ffmpeg.probe(path_video_file)
    # from the dictionary, meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate'] is the key
    # we are looking for
    rotate_code = None
    rotate = meta_dict.get('streams', [dict(tags=dict())])[0].get('tags', dict()).get('rotate', 0)
    return round(int(rotate) / 90.0) * 90
```

Comment: ` # check if the frame needs to be rotated
    if rotateCode is not None:
        frame = correct_rotation(frame, rotateCode)`

Takes care of that problem

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this in your frame processing loop:

```
frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
```

The 0 flips vertically, see Open CV documentation for more info.

Comment: This is not the way to detect if a video is rotated or not.

Comment: The question doesn't ask the way to detect if a video is rotated or not.

Comment: "So from this, how can I deal with a video that has a rotation?" literally mentioned in the OPs question

Comment: Right! And a possible answer is: you can flip it. You are reading more into the question than is there. The question did not say "How can I detect..." it said "How can I deal with ..."